# Resharper suggestion Page_Load = PageLoad

Tags: naming-conventions, resharper, pageload

Usually when the `Page_Load` event handler is added to a codebehind file by Visual Studio (e.g. double clicking the page in designer mode), it ends up looking like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles the Load event of the Page control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

But Resharper suggests `Name 'Page_Load' does not match rule 'Methods, properties and events'. Suggested name is 'PageLoad'`. I'm guessing there's a better way to define the handler for page load, but I can't remember what the syntax is, but I imagine it would resolve this Resharper warning?

Perhaps something like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Raises the <see cref="E:System.Web.UI.Control.Load"/> event.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="T:System.EventArgs"/> object that contains the event data.</param>
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    // ...
}
```

but I seem to recall that `OnLoad` and `PageLoad` aren't exactly the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OnLoad` and `Page_Load` **are** essentially the same. `Page_Load` is invoked via reflection if AutoEventWireup is enabled on the `Page`. OnLoad is a protected virtual method of the `Control` class (which the `Page` class inherits).

See [Inside AutoEventWireup](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/02/16/inside-autoeventwireup.aspx) for an in-depth analysis of how AutoEventWireup works and why it exists.

The StackOverflow community also has some [input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147033/when-creating-a-web-control-should-you-override-onload-or-implement-page-load) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464898/difference-between-page-load-and-onload) [whether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329090/base-onloade-in-a-asp-net-page) [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737092/how-to-execute-page-load-in-pages-base-class) [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494543/what-calls-page-load-and-how-does-it-do-it) [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563594/autoeventwireup-and-base-onloade-calling-self-resulting-in-stack-overflo) to handle the `Load` event or override the `OnLoad` method.

Answer (score 44):

Just for completeness I thought I would add here the answer you got from one "David Benson" [when you asked on jetbrains.net](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5272088):

> If you go to ReSharper Options, under Languages select C# Naming Style.  Select the Advanced settings... button and in the `Event subscriptions on fields:`, remove the `On` in front of `$event$` so it is `$object$_$event$`.  That should remove the warning.

For me this is the easiest way of placating ReSharper in the face of a large existing web application codebase.

Comment: IMHO, this is the correct answer to the question (+1 because it helped me out)

Comment: I agree. This is a simpler solution to the problem. Seems like a bug in R# to me that by default, it won't warn if you use Page_OnLoad.

Comment: beauty, this issue has bugged me for months and I never bothered to look it up.  This gets rid of the warnings for Page_Load Page_Init etc, but keeps warnings for all other warnings in tact.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in ReSharper 6.0 and lower. In 6.1 it's fixed.
For AutoEventWireup handlers it will not suggest any changes doesn't matter which naming settings you have.